# Java ReplaceAll doesn't help me here

Tags: java, regex, replace

I have a String here,

```
String message = "hi test message >< abcd < pqr <variable> xyz <tag> testing <>";
```

I want to replace all `<>`  `<tag>` `<anything>` with `(.*)` as i am trying to build a regex out of it.

I tried the following,

```
message = message.replaceAll("<(.*)>", "(.*)");
```

but the result is

```
hi test message >(.*)
```

the result i am expecting is this

```
hi test message >< abcd < pqr (.*) xyz (.*) testing (.*)
```

Can anyone help me to acheive this result?

ThankYou in advance!

Comment: Is there a reason why `<variable>` is not replaced in your expected result?

Comment: `< abcd < pqr <variable> xyz <tag> testing <>` This is replaced instead!

Comment: Hmm, so `<anything>` is really meant literally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To catch tag contents, try this regexp (assuming they're never nested):

```
<([^<>])*>
```

Note that this will completely ignore this part of your test string:

```
< abcd < pqr
```

Comment: Yep, but actually there is no need for capture from what the expected result is. +1 for using a complemented character class instead of a lazy quantifier!

Comment: @fge - youre right. the capture is because whenever i had to do this sort of thing the value inside the tag was of interest.

Answer (score 2):

Use Following regular expression to remove all type of tags.

```
@"(?></?\w+)(?>(?:[^>'""]+|'[^']*'|""[^""]*"")*)|(?>(?:[>'""]+|'[^']*'|""[^""]*"")*)"
```

Answer (score 1):

Provided you really mean to only replace `<>`, `<tag>`, `<anything>` and nothing else, try:

```
<(tag|anything)?>
```

If you want to match all enclosed tags, including empty ones:

```
<[^<>]*>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regular expression

```
"<(|tag|anything)>"
```

Comment: No need to put parens around `tag` or `anything`